# How to ignore mouse moves over hidden part of NSView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, nsview

I have some window which in turn contains an NSView, *v1*. The view can receive events from mouse, like Mouse Down, Enter, Exit and so on. The view can be overlapped by other view (*v2*) (modal window not involved). 
I want to be able receive events Enter/Exit in *v1* when the mouse is over **visible** part of *v1*, and ignore those events when the mouse is over **hidden** region.

How? Enlighten me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually in my case solution was pretty simple: options for NSTrackingArea should include **NSTrackingInVisibleRect**